# Graphql request returning 404 error in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql

I created a Graphql project with Spring Boot. When I hit the graphql endpoint from postman it throws a 404 error. I thought there is some dependency issue so I tried different dependencies as mentioned below in the pom.xml file but it didn't resolve the issue. I am completely new to graphql and cannot understand where the issue is

Query Class

```
package com.gql.graphql;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.coxautodev.graphql.tools.GraphQLQueryResolver;


@Component
public class Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver{
    public String firstQuery() {
        return "first query";
    }

}
```

query.graphqls

```
type Query{
    firstQuery:String
}
```

application.properties

```
server.port=8681
graphql.servlet.mapping=/graphql
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.gql</groupId>
    <artifactId>gql</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>gql</name>
    <description>Demo project for gql</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.graphql-java-kickstart</groupId> <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId> 
            <version>14.0.0</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-graphql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java-tools</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphiql-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Postman error

[image]